# Looping this guessing game continuously

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, for-loop, while-loop

I'm fairly new to java and I was wondering how could I reset this game to ask another number after the user guessed it correctly?

Here's my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Question2 {

   public static void main(String args[]) {
      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
         int count = 0;
         int a = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 99);
         int guess = 0;

      System.out.println("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game");
      System.out.print("Guess a number between 0 and 100 or enter -1 to end: ");

    while (guess != a) {
    guess = keyboard.nextInt();
     count++;
    if (guess < 0 || guess > 100){
     if(guess == -1){
        System.out.print("Thank you for playing the game!");
             break;
      }
        System.out.print("Out of bounds. Try Again: ");
        continue;
    }
    if (guess > a) {
        System.out.print("The number is lower. Try again: ");
    }
    else if (guess < a) {
        System.out.print("The number is higher. Try again: ");
    }
    else if (guess == a) {
    System.out.println("Congratulations. You guessed the number in "
    + count + " tries!");
    }  
   }

}
}
```

Comment: No do...while in the answers? I'm disappointed :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap your entire code (except for the scanner initialization) in a `while` loop that is always true. That way, when one game ends, it will start a new one. Then, instead of `break`ing your game's `while` loop when the user enters a `-1`, just use `System.exit(0)`, which will end your program with a status code of `0`, indicating that the program executed successfully.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        int count = 0;
        int a = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 99);
        int guess = 0;

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game");
        System.out.print("Guess a number between 0 and 100 or enter -1 to end: ");

        while (guess != a) {
            guess = keyboard.nextInt();
            count++;
            if (guess < 0 || guess > 100) {
                if (guess == -1) {
                    System.out.print("Thank you for playing the game!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
                System.out.print("Out of bounds. Try Again: ");
                continue;
            }
            if (guess > a) {
                System.out.print("The number is lower. Try again: ");
            } else if (guess < a) {
                System.out.print("The number is higher. Try again: ");
            } else if (guess == a) {
                System.out.println("Congratulations. You guessed the number in "
                        + count + " tries!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

- move your **end game condition** in the `while` condition like this `while(guess != -1)`
- move the *welcome* greetings inside the loop
- move the *thank you* greeting after the game loop is done
- reset `count` and `a` when the user won a game in order to start *fresh*
- reset `guess` on every iteration

Now even if the player guesses the number, the loop **does not** end and the *game loop* can be stopped only intentionally (by entering -1 = current break condition):

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Question2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int count = 0;
        int a = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 99);
        int guess = 0;

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game");
        while (guess != -1) {
            System.out.print("Guess a number between 0 and 100 or enter -1 to end: ");
            guess = keyboard.nextInt();
            count++;
            if (guess < 0 || guess > 100){
                System.out.print("Out of bounds. Try Again: ");
                continue;
            }
            if (guess > a) {
                System.out.print("The number is lower. Try again: ");
            }
            else if (guess < a) {
                System.out.print("The number is higher. Try again: ");
            }
            else if (guess == a) {
                a = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 99);
                System.out.println("Congratulations. You guessed the number in " + count + " tries!");
                count = 0;
            }
            guess = 0;
        }
        System.out.print("Thank you for playing the game!");
}
```

The code can be refactored even more, for example extract functionality into functions in order to make the code more readable. This also leads to easier maintanence should the variables change or should more conditions come. For example the code can be refactored like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Question2 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int a = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int guess = 0;

        startNewGame();

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game");

        while (guess != -1) {
            System.out.print("Guess a number between 0 and 100 or enter -1 to end: ");
            guess = keyboard.nextInt();
            count++;
            if (guess < 0 || guess > 100){
                System.out.print("Out of bounds. Try Again: ");
                continue;
            }
            if (guess > a) {
                System.out.print("The number is lower. Try again: ");
            }
            else if (guess < a) {
                System.out.print("The number is higher. Try again: ");
            }
            else if (guess == a) {
                System.out.println("Congratulations. You guessed the number in " + count + " tries!");
                startNewGame();
            }
            resetGuess();
        }
        System.out.print("Thank you for playing the game!");
    }

    private static int generateNewA() {
        return 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 99);
    }

    private static void startNewGame() {
        a = generateNewA();
        count = 0;
    }

    private static void resetGuess() {
        guess = 0;
    }
}
```

Another solution is to use two nested loops, but IMO for this case *loop in a loop* is too much and makes the source unnecessary complex.

Comment: This doesn't update `a` which is the random number generated every time you play the game.

Comment: @gonzo then move `a`also in the while loop body!

Comment: ;) yup that would fix it.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Now `a` is generated over and over on every loop.

Comment: Number of guesses don't get reverted back to zero when a new game starts. :p

Comment: @gonzo Thanks - fixed that too. ;-)

Comment: number of guesses is in variable `count`. That is the one that you should be setting to 0.

Comment: Also you do not want to change `count` and `a` after every iteration in the `while` loop but instead after every game.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your code in a `while (true)` this will keep on running your code for ever and ever. Make sure you are also updating your random `a` after every game and your `count`. Then from there just check if guess is ever `-1` and `return` when it is. When you call `return` it will end the method which ends your game.

```
Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true){
    int count = 0;
    int a = 1 + (int) (Math.random() * 99);
    int guess = 0;
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Number Guessing Game");
    System.out.print("Guess a number between 0 and 100 or enter -1 to end: ");

    while (guess != a) {
        guess = keyboard.nextInt();
        count++;
        if (guess==-1){
            System.out.print("Thank you for playing the game!");
            return;
        }else if (guess < 0 || guess > 100){
            System.out.print("Out of bounds. Try Again: ");
            continue;
        }
        if (guess > a) {
            System.out.print("The number is lower. Try again: ");
        }
        else if (guess < a) {
            System.out.print("The number is higher. Try again: ");
        }
        else if (guess == a) {
            System.out.println("Congratulations. You guessed the number in "
                    + count + " tries!");
        }  
    }

}
```

Comment: i need to just continue looping the whole program without the "do you want to play again?". How do I loop that?

Comment: @anthony Do you never want to stop? What is the condition you want to use to stop the program?

Comment: so program will ask the user to guess a number then after the user guessed it correctly it will ask another number again, and so on.the user will enter "-1" to quit the program.

Comment: @anthony I have updated my answer to fit what you are trying to accomplish.